# Leaked window when try to show Dialog

Tags: android, android-widget

I have inside onCreate method code like this

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Ex.this);
            builder.setMessage(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.title))
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.ok),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.Cancel),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                }
                            }).create().show();
```

but I get ***leaked window*** error always. Can anybody tell me what is wrong ? I tried to replace Ex.this with getApplicationContext() but that didn't help.

Comment: Following links may be useful to you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added][1]


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181508/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181508/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `dialog.show()` directly. Instead, go through `onCreateDialog()`.

See API Demos for examples: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html