# android posting on server database error k

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i'm trying to post on the servers database 
didn't know where is the error exactly but it seems to be in the Asynctask check out the logcat

so I'm really not sure if the error comes from the PHP files or the Java code

```
 07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688): Activity com.example.ahliaevents.AddCard has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@421da710 that was originally added here
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.ahliaevents.AddCard has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@421da710 that was originally added here
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at com.example.ahliaevents.AddCard$CreateNewCard.onPreExecute(AddCard.java:75)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at com.example.ahliaevents.AddCard$1.onClick(AddCard.java:55)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-07 20:07:30.533: E/WindowManager(1688):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my class

```
public class AddCard extends Activity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName,inputPhone,inputPosition,inputCollege;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_card = "#####://####/####/#####.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addcard);

        // Edit Text
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addstudentname);
        inputCollege = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addstudentcollege);
        inputPosition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addstudentposition);
        inputPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addstudentphone);

        // Create button
        Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addcardsave);

        // button click event
        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewCard().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */
    class CreateNewCard extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialo
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddCard.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Student Card..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            String position = inputPosition.getText().toString();
            String college = inputCollege.getText().toString();
            String phone = inputPhone.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("position", position));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("college", college));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_card,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The stacktrace says it all: you have a `NullPointerException` at line 83 in `AddCard.java`. Could you post the `AddCard` class? Or at least the part containing the line with the error

Comment: yes i've posted it check it out

Comment: Looking at the entire class is a little hard at detecting the specific line. Can you point out which is line 83?

Comment: its String position = inputPosition.getText().toString();

i found out that i didn't declare  inputPosition as an edit text 

but still there's another issues

Comment: Judging by that, most probably `inputPosition` is null, causing the `NPE`

Comment: i've corrected it but still the application breaks

Comment: i'll add the new logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not the server side error. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/9492974/2069130 and understand error. Actually, you can't do some kind of UI actions in doInBackGround. You have to either put that piece of code in onPostExecute or you have to use

```
Activity_Name.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your stuff to update the UI

            }
        });
```

around that code

Comment: Also try to search "Activity has leaked window that was originally added here" to get more help

Comment: didn't understand Inn_vita answer

Comment: Simple solution, but not a good one: try to put all the doInBackground data/functionality in place of comment in above given solution i.e. "// your stuff to update the UI" and run it

Comment: i'm not doing anything about UI in this activity ,, i'm just posting data on server

Comment: dear, UI means user interface and what you think what is inputName, inputPosition (i.e. edit-texts) here. They are the UIs. So follow the 3rd comment of this post.

Comment: OR move the above portion of doInBackground in your main activity and send List<NameValuePair> as an argument to doInBackground inspite of a string

Comment: I'll check the solution just after i check my PHP files it seems they're not posting anything also thanks mate I'll give you a feedback