# Android: Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView that was originally added here

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am receiving the above error when launching my application in version 3.1 in my tablet

It works fine from 2.1 to 2.3 on phones

The code it complains about is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    // Other logic here
            // ....
    showDialog(Constants.INTRODUCTION_DIALOG);
}
```

What is the problem here? I see other related threads but I don't see one similar to my problem on launch.

Thanks

Comment: are you passing the context in your dialog

Comment: I am passing the Application to it

Comment: can you post you code for dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181508/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie/5182159#5182159

Answer (score 1):

May you need call the `dialog.dismiss()` before your activity is finished.
If your dialog is a confirm dialog(yes/cancel) and you want to finish the activity from which the dialog shows when user click the yes/cancel button, you need call `dialog.dismiss()` in the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` of the yes/cancle button.

[see also here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000940/android-activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindow)