# android activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.phonewindow$decorview Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, memory-leaks, android-alertdialog

I am working with Android application to show network error.

**NetErrorPage.java**

```
package exp.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class NetErrorPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.neterrorlayout);
        Button reload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReload);
        reload.setOnClickListener(this);    
        showInfoMessageDialog("Please check your network connection","Network Alert"); 
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0)             
        {
            if(isNetworkAvailable())
            {                   
                Intent myIntent = new Intent((Activity)NetErrorPage.this, MainActivity.class);   
                myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);              
                ((Activity)NetErrorPage.this).startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
            else
                showInfoMessageDialog("Please check your network connection","Network Alert");
    }

    public void showInfoMessageDialog(String message,String title)
       {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NetErrorPage.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Network Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
                    {   
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });            
        alertDialog.show();
    }

 private boolean isNetworkAvailable()
    {
        NetworkInfo ActiveNetwork;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String IsNetworkConnected;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String ConnectionType;
        ConnectivityManager connectivitymanager;
        connectivitymanager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);        
        try
        {           
            ActiveNetwork=connectivitymanager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            ConnectionType=ActiveNetwork.getTypeName(); 
            IsNetworkConnected=String.valueOf(ActiveNetwork.getState());
            return true;                        
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
                return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

but i'm getting the error as below,

```
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460): Activity exp.app.NetErrorPage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40534a18 that was originally added here
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity exp.app.NetErrorPage has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40534a18 that was originally added here
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:263)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at sync.directtrac.NetError.showInfoMessageDialog(NetErrorPage.java:114)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at sync.directtrac.NetError.onCreate(NetErrorPage.java:26)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-17 11:59:08.019: E/WindowManager(16460):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have searched more... but i don't have any right idea to clear this.

What i want is, when loading this page, layout should be added and dialog should be shown.

Please help me to clear this error

**Note:** I have tried this also

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showInfoMessageDialog("Please check your network connection","Network Alert");
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What `showInfoMessageDialog` method contains?

Comment: i have edited my code... please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added

Comment: @Eric: that is to show dialog when clicking on the button, but i'm asking to show oncreate

Comment: Same cause; the `Dialog` is being added in a window that doesn't exist.

Comment: Clean your project and try to run

Comment: @SpK: getting the same error....

Comment: My Activity name is NetErrorPage

Comment: Did you try to use activity methods onCreateDialog(int),onPrepareDialog(),showDialog() or launch this on another device?

Comment: @Yahor10: I could not understand what you are asking

Comment: Activity has methods to create dialog.Use them to show your error dialog.

Comment: what code is on NetErrorPage.java:114 ?

Comment: @ChiragRaval: Other than the above code, having code for button click...

Comment: show me code what is on 114 line . please

Comment: @user370305: just i started this as intent from my main activity

Comment: @ChiragRaval: 114 th line is " alertDialog.show();"

Comment: @user370305: Sorry, I wan to show alert dialog when the page is loading

Comment: Please check my whole source code

Comment: @user370305: please check my Note:

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Thank you Guys to give me many suggestions**. Finally I got a solution. That is i have started the NetErrorPage intent two times. One time, i have checked the net connection availability and started the intent in page started event. second time, if the page has error, then i have started the intent in OnReceivedError event. So the first time dialog is not closed, before that the second dialog is called. So that i got a error.

> **Reason for the Error**: I have called the showInfoMessageDialog method
>   two times before closing the first one.

Now I have removed the second call and Cleared error :-).

Comment: My understanding we can not called second dialog before closing first one ? please correct me if i am worng.

Comment: @Lavekush: We can open many dialogs at a time but if the dialog is in new activity and you are invoking intent to call that dialog will cause the error. if you are calling from the activity and the dialog is in the same activity will not cause the error i hope.

Answer (score 60):

Change this `dialog.cancel();` to `dialog.dismiss();`

The solution is to call `dismiss()` on the `Dialog` you created in **NetErrorPage.java:114** before exiting the `Activity`, e.g. in `onPause()`.

Views have a reference to their parent `Context` (taken from constructor argument). If you leave an `Activity` without destroying `Dialog`s and other dynamically created `View`s, they still hold this reference to your `Activity` (if you created with this as `Context`: like `new ProgressDialog(this)`), so it cannot be collected by the GC, causing a memory leak.

Comment: please check my edited code, tell me what i have to change in that

Comment: @Ponmalar , i checked your code and i think i got error . please override onPause method in this activity and dismiss your alert dialog in that. You should have create AlertDialog alertDialog variable at class level (means declared it before onCreate method and dimiss it in onPause Method . This Will solve your problem)

Comment: I got a solution.... your suggestion may give solution to others, so giving up vote

Comment: @Ponmalar what is the solution ? Can you describe here ?

Comment: nice & short description why this happens

Comment: Thanks. In my case instead of dialog.hide() must be written dialog.dismiss();

Comment: If you see the code of `cancel()` function, it already calls `dismiss()` internally but additionally it will also call your `DialogInterface.OnCancelListener` (if registered).

So giving preference to one over another won't theoretically make a difference.

Comment: `@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
//APP WILL CRASH IF THIS IS NOT PRESENT
 loadingDialog.dismiss();
}`

Answer (score 5):

Please try this Way And Let me know :

```
Context mContext;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.neterrorlayout);

   mContext=NetErrorPage.this;
   Button reload=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReload);
   reload.setOnClickListener(this);    
   showInfoMessageDialog("Please check your network connection","Network Alert"); 
}
public void showInfoMessageDialog(String message,String title)
{
   new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
   .setTitle("Network Alert");
   .setMessage(message);
   .setButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
       {   
          dialog.cancel();
       }
   })
   .show();
}
```

Comment: It's a totally Context Issue.Nothing Else.

Comment: Very Sorry Haresh, Check my edited code. My actvity name is "NetErrorPage"

Comment: PLease Paste the whole Activity Code.

Comment: please check my edited code, tell me what i have to change in that

Comment: I got a solution.... your suggestion may give solution to others, so giving up vote

Answer (score 5):

In my case `finish()` executed immediately after a dialog has shown.

Comment: Even pause() causes this with me

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, what method do you mean? `onPause()`?

Comment: Yes, it causes window leak also for displayed windows / dialogs

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, thanks. If you know a command that leads to `onPause()` you can write it as a new answer or here.

Answer (score 3):

The dialog needs to be started only after the window states of the Activity are initialized
This happens only after onresume.

So call

```
runOnUIthread(new Runnable(){

    showInfoMessageDialog("Please check your network connection","Network Alert");
});
```

in your OnResume function. Do not create dialogs in OnCreate
**Edit:**

use this

```
Handler h = new Handler();

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        showInfoMessageDialog("Please check your network connection","Network Alert");
    },500);
```

in your Onresume instead of showonuithread

Comment: please check my edited code, tell me what i have to change in that

Comment: use this in onresume instead showInfoMessageDialog in oncreate

Comment: super call should always be at top of onresume

Comment: I got a solution.... your suggestion may give solution to others, so giving up vote

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mProgressDialog = null;
```

setting the value null works for me

Answer (score 0):

I got this error but it is resolved interesting. As first, i got this error at api level 17. When i call a thread (AsyncTask or others) without progress dialog then i call an other thread method again using progress dialog, i got that crash and the reason is about usage of progress dialog.

In my case, there are two results that;

- I took `show();` method of progress dialog before first thread starts then i took `dismiss();` method of progress dialog before last thread ends.

So :

```
ProgresDialog progressDialog = new ...

//configure progressDialog 

progressDialog.show();

start firstThread {
...
}

...

start lastThread {
...
} 

//be sure to finish threads

progressDialog.dismiss();
```

- This is so strange but that error has an ability about destroy itself at least for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this issue is by not calling intent within a dialog. 
      **** use syntax applicable to activity or fragment accordingly

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    checkvariable= true;
    getActivity().finish();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (checkvariable) {
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
}
```