# Getting window leaked error when trying to auto reload app

Tags: android, timertask

I am trying to get my app to auto reload every 15 seconds but when I execute the function, I am getting a window leaked error.

Error log:

```
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.weatherapp.piwe.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b19372c0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-729,192} that was originally added here
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at com.weatherapp.piwe.MainActivity$JSONWeatherTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:166)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at com.weatherapp.piwe.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:406)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-16 23:40:17.708: E/WindowManager(2087):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is the current way I am using correct for an auto reload function?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final String city = "";

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    pi = intent.getStringExtra("pi");
    Log.d("PI", pi);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
    condDescr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.condDescr);
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.condIcon);

    // Create and populate a List of variable names.
    String[] weather = new String[] {};
    ArrayList<String> weatherData = new ArrayList<String>();
    weatherData.addAll(Arrays.asList(weather));

    listAdapter = new WeatherAdapter(this, weatherData);

    JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { city });

    ImageButton picture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPicturePage);
    picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent startPic = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    PicturePage.class);
            startPic.putExtra("date", date);
            startPic.putExtra("pi", pi);
            startActivity(startPic);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.selectPi1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Pi 1 is currently not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        return true;
    case R.id.selectPi2:
        Intent i2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i2.putExtra("pi", "pi2");
        finish();
        startActivity(i2);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

        List<NameValuePair> params2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pi", pi));

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params2));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
            Log.d("JSON OUT", response);
            if (response == null) {
                showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this);
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            uhe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e4) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e4.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);
        } catch (JSONException e3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            json = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (JSONException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            weatherD = json.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER);
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject c = weatherD.getJSONObject(0);
            temp = c.getString(TAG_TEMP);
            nTemp = temp.replace('*', '°');
            pressure = c.getString(TAG_PRESSURE);
            humid = c.getString(TAG_HUMIDITY);
            ac = c.getString(TAG_AC);
            int aq = Integer.parseInt(ac);
            if (aq <= 150) {
                airq = "Good";
            } else if (aq <= 300) {
                airq = "Moderate";
            } else if (aq <= 500) {
                airq = "Unhealthy";
            } else if (aq <= 700) {
                airq = "Very Unhealthy";
            } else {
                airq = "HARZADOUS!";
            }
            dateO = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
            Date dateD = null;
            try {
                dateD = formatter.parse(dateO);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", java.util.Locale.getDefault());
            date = formatter2.format(dateD);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return weather;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
        super.onPostExecute(weather);

        Drawable day = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear_day);
        Drawable night = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear_night);
        Drawable cloud = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloudy);
        Drawable haze = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.haze);
        Drawable rain = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rain);
        Drawable thunder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunder);

        String code = weather.currentCondition.getIcon();

        if (code.equals("01d") || code.equals("02d")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(day);
        } else if (code.equals("01n") || code.equals("02n")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(night);
        } else if (code.startsWith("03") || code.startsWith("04")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(cloud);
        } else if (code.startsWith("09") || code.startsWith("10")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(rain);
        } else if (code.startsWith("11")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(thunder);
        } else if (code.startsWith("50")) {
            imgView.setImageDrawable(haze);
        }

        cityText.setText("Cyberjaya" + ", " + weather.location.getCountry()
                + " - " + pi);
        if (weather.currentCondition.getCondition().equals("Clouds")) {
            condDescr.setText("Weather: Cloudy");
            weatherS = "Cloudy";
        } else {
            condDescr.setText("Weather: "
                    + weather.currentCondition.getCondition());
            weatherS = weather.currentCondition.getCondition();
        }
        listAdapter.add("Temperature: " + "\t\t\t\t" + nTemp);
        listAdapter.add("Humidity: " + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + humid);
        listAdapter.add("Air pressure: " + "\t\t\t\t" + pressure);
        listAdapter.add("Air quality: " + "\t\t\t\t\t" + airq + " (" + ac
                + ")");
        listAdapter.add("Updated on: " + "\t\t\t\t" + date);

        pDialog.dismiss();



        // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        callAsynchronousTask();
    }
}

public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // Class that extends AsynchTask
                        JSONWeatherTask backgroundTask = new JSONWeatherTask();
                        backgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 15000); // execute in every 15
                                                    // seconds
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000940/android-activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindow   Check this post...

Answer (score 0):

May be this is due to the way of Dismissing Dialog in Post Execute Method 
Just Try to do Like This :

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
    super.onPostExecute(weather);

    Drawable day = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear_day);
    Drawable night = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.clear_night);
    Drawable cloud = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloudy);
    Drawable haze = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.haze);
    Drawable rain = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rain);
    Drawable thunder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.thunder);

    String code = weather.currentCondition.getIcon();

    if (code.equals("01d") || code.equals("02d")) {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(day);
    } else if (code.equals("01n") || code.equals("02n")) {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(night);
    } else if (code.startsWith("03") || code.startsWith("04")) {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(cloud);
    } else if (code.startsWith("09") || code.startsWith("10")) {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(rain);
    } else if (code.startsWith("11")) {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(thunder);
    } else if (code.startsWith("50")) {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(haze);
    }

    cityText.setText("Cyberjaya" + ", " + weather.location.getCountry()
            + " - " + pi);
    if (weather.currentCondition.getCondition().equals("Clouds")) {
        condDescr.setText("Weather: Cloudy");
        weatherS = "Cloudy";
    } else {
        condDescr.setText("Weather: "
                + weather.currentCondition.getCondition());
        weatherS = weather.currentCondition.getCondition();
    }
    listAdapter.add("Temperature: " + "\t\t\t\t" + nTemp);
    listAdapter.add("Humidity: " + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + humid);
    listAdapter.add("Air pressure: " + "\t\t\t\t" + pressure);
    listAdapter.add("Air quality: " + "\t\t\t\t\t" + airq + " (" + ac
            + ")");
    listAdapter.add("Updated on: " + "\t\t\t\t" + date);





    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    callAsynchronousTask();
     pDialog.dismiss();

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: i now have ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at `String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));`

Comment: Its problem because of your Array, Why are you accessing static array Location.?

Comment: I think hrer params is a url array so you are accessing it, So for testing just put this line. String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(url));  whatever your urlstring is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dismiss method with your dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `finish()` before executing the task works.

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Class that extends AsyncTask
                    JSONWeatherTask backgroundTask = new JSONWeatherTask();
                    finish();  //<------here
                    backgroundTask.execute();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 15000); // execute in every 15
                                                // seconds
```