# Android activity has java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView Exception and get crashed

Tags: android

It got below error sometime when android activity is starting.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{16055902
>   V.E..... R......D 0,0-639,154} not attached to window manager

[image]

This is my .java file
Step 1 : InviteFriendsActivity.java
    public class InviteFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    @Bind(R.id.btn_invite)
    MonoserratRegularButton btnInvite;
    @Bind(R.id.ll_main)
    LinearLayout llMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invite_friends);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        btnInvite.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Step2 :Login.java

```
private void loadUrl(boolean isTrue) {

    mApp = new InstagramApp(this, ApplicationData.CLIENT_ID,
            ApplicationData.CLIENT_SECRET, ApplicationData.CALLBACK_URL, isTrue);

    mApp.setListener(new InstagramApp.OAuthAuthenticationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // tvSummary.setText("Connected as " + mApp.getUserName());
            // userInfoHashmap = mApp.
            mApp.fetchUserName(handler);
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,InviteFriendsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String error) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Share your activity code. Are you showing a dialog at the beginning?

Comment: no im not showing any dialog @ beginning @Shaishav

Comment: this error occurs sometime not every time so i'm confused @DysaniazzZ!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000940/android-activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindow

Comment: but i'm not using any dialog i'm integrated instagram and on success result i'm open this activity and get crashed!! @DysaniazzZ

Comment: I can't see any wrong in your code. And I wanna know where do your start your `InviteFriendsActivity`, do your review the code from that class?

Comment: I guess it's the `handler` that cause the error. What do you do in `mApp.fetchUserName(handler);`?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ You must be using dialog somewhere. Check the InviteFriendsActivity in your manifest and it's theme, and check your fetchUserName method as well.