# How to get rid of "has leaked window"?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, progressdialog, progress

I have looked through google but all the answers that I have found does't related to my issue...

There is my error log

```
Activity com.fittingroom.newtimezone.view.ActivityAcceptNotAccept has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{57b68a6 V.ED..... R......D 0,0-324,534} that was originally added here
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:565)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:326)
                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:350)
                                                                        at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.view.ActivityAcceptNotAccept.openProgress(ActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:125)
                                                                        at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.openProgress(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:125)
                                                                        at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.access$000(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:16)
                                                                        at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept$1.onPreExecute(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:35)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
                                                                        at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.setCroppedPreviewImage(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:51)
                                                                        at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.view.ActivityAcceptNotAccept.accept(ActivityAcceptNotAccept.java:63)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4735)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

What I am doing, I just create progress dialog and under controll of assynk task and in `onPreExecute()` dialog is opening and therefore in `onPostExecute()` dialog is closing...

There is my code

```
public final class ActivityAcceptNotAccept extends Activity implements IActivityAcceptNotAccept {

private Dialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accept_not_accept);

    ...///

    presenter.initView();


}

...///

@Override
public void initView() {
    progressDialog = UtilClass.getDialog(ActivityAcceptNotAccept.this, getString(R.string.loading));
}

public final void accept(View view) {
    switch (count) {
        case firstClick:
            presenter.setCroppedPreviewImage();
            break;
        case secondClick:
            presenter.setResultOkAndFinishActivity();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void setDisplaySize() {
    UtilClass.setDisplaySize(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(), getWindow(), 95, 95);
}

@Override
public void openProgress() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}

@Override
public void closeProgress() {
    if (progressDialog != null) {
        progressDialog.cancel();
        progressDialog = null;
    }
}
}
```

There is a method whicth provide me `Dialog` instance

```
public abstract class UtilClass {

public static Dialog getDialog(Context context, String text) {
    final Dialog progressDialog = new Dialog(context);
    progressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    final Window window = progressDialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }else {
        Logger.logError("window == null", new NullPointerException(), context);
    }

    final TextView msg = (TextView) progressDialog.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_loadingmsg);
    msg.setText(text);

    return progressDialog;
}
```

As I can understand there is nothing spesial just create dialog , show it and eventually close it that is it ...

Why I get this error?

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

AsynkTask

```
public void setCroppedPreviewImage() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, byte[]>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            openProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            final String path = model.getImageFilePath();
            final Bitmap croppedBitmap = getCroppedBitmapFromPath(path);
            return getByteArrayFromBitmap(croppedBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            closeProgress();
            iActivityAcceptNotAccept.setPreviewImage(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: this error occur when Dialog method call two times before closing the first one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000940/android-activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindow

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes I saw this answer, but it is imposible for me... I invoked dialog just one time... But anyway I have to check

Comment: code edit `public void closeProgress() {
    if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressDialog = null;
    }`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya added

Comment: modify `closeProgress()` . call `.dismiss()` instead of `cancel()`

Comment: I changed `.dismiss()` instead of `cancel()`, but it doesn't matter. I have accomplished debag and `openProgress()` method was invocked once and than once `closeProgress()` all is ok first time, but if i repeatedly try invoke `openProgress()` dialog appear and in second I have got error in   `openProgress()` method although dialog had already invoked and appeared... Weird

Comment: I usually find this Exception happens when you try to open a Dialog after the Activity has already closed / started closing. Can that be the case here?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko thats the reason you should check dialog `isShowing()`

Comment: @Knossos  no... in my case I do it in one activity without closing...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko did you solve this yet ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya yes, I published my answer

Answer (score 1):

actually in my case reason was not in progress dialog. I tryed to delete progress and genuine reason unveiled. It was due to OOM during bitmap decode process... But I don't know why I got error log which said that reason in `progress dialog` .

Eventually my bitmap was to big and I had to reduce it

I accomplished this way(if someone will have the same issue)

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photo.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

It means that I reduce bitmap size in 2 times and now app works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to see you fix that issue .move ahead

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
public void closeDialog() { 
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) 
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
public void displayDialog() { 
    if (progressDialog != null && !progressDialog.isShowing()) 
    {
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```