# How to fix has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow in Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

In my application i want show dialog, and for this this write below codes. 
But when run application not show me dialog and show this error in logCat.

**My logCat error :**

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.app.android.Activity.DetailPage.RegisterInAuctionActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1e27b62 V.E...... R.....I. 0,0-0,0} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:377)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
    at com.app.android.Activity.DetailPage.RegisterInAuctionActivity$2$1.onResponse(RegisterInAuctionActivity.java:372)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5530)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:733)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
```

**My java codes:**

```
Call<DetailResponse> call2 = apIs.getDetainAuctions(detail.getId().toString(), jwtToken, "android");
call2.enqueue(new Callback<DetailResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<DetailResponse> call, final Response<DetailResponse> response) {
        if (response.body() != null) {
            if (response.body().getRes() != null) {
                if (response.body().getRes().getAccount() != null) {
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            footerFragment.update(response.body().getRes().getAccount().getBuyBid(), isUpdateInfo);
                        }
                    }, 200);
                    dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.important_note);
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);

                    LinearLayout closeDialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.okPayFrag_submitOK);
                    closeDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<DetailResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

How can i fix this bug ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.phonewindow$decorview Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000940/android-activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindow)