# JSON parsing issue not resolved

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

My LogCat errors are:

```
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420): Activity com.example.visit.record.My_Task has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054ed00 that was originally added here
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.visit.record.My_Task has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4054ed00 that was originally added here
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:277)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at com.example.visit.record.My_Task$GetTaskDetails.onPreExecute(My_Task.java:137)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at com.example.visit.record.My_Task.onCreate(My_Task.java:105)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4268)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    12-31 14:45:14.920: E/WindowManager(3420):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 14:54:22.360: E/AndroidRuntime(4423):     at com.example.visit.record.My_Task$GetTaskDetails.doInBackground(My_Task.java:163)
12-31 15:10:51.470: W/System.err(6457):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-31 15:10:51.470: W/System.err(6457):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-31 15:10:51.470: W/System.err(6457):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
12-31 15:10:51.480: E/Buffer Error(6457): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 15:10:51.480: E/JSON Parser(6457): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-31 15:10:51.480: W/dalvikvm(6457): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-31 15:10:51.490: E/AndroidRuntime(6457):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
```

I got error on **dialog.show();** in Preexecute dialog in getTaskDetail class . and display an error on         **Log.d("Single Task Details", json.toString());**  and got an error on    **new GetTaskDetails().execute();**

Kindly guide why it doesn't get values from my php application database. and it stopped unexpectedly by generating an error of "Force Close". Kindly guide where i go wrong. I want to get data from MySql to android using JSONParsing

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem in url while running in emulator change url to

this

```
private static final String url_read_mytask = "http://10.0.2.2/evisiting_records/read_mytask.php";
```

and

```
private static final String url_update_mytask = "http://10.0.2.2/evisiting_records/update_mytask.php"
```

Comment: I am running it on HTC. but not getting data

Comment: but try once with this code.

Comment: i try it:) but not getting data:) generating error of "Force Close" kindly guide..

Comment: Try this Link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Its no problem of json it seams that you try to interact with ui thread from background thread.
Have a look at: 
[Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46368a28 that was originally added here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181508/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with your JSON which causes the leaking window:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Can you post the JSON (by opening the url in the browser or CURL and copying contents). The JSON seems to be invalid.